# Getting error without location: "svn: E175011: Repository moved permanently; please relocate"

Tags: svn

I am unable to checkout code from http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk as i am getting error

> svn: E175011: Repository moved permanently; please relocate

But i dont see any alternate location

Comment: Note that the viewvc URL is for use with the web browser.  Use the URL provided by mcgyver5 below.  If you use a client newer than 1.7.0 it'll handle this automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got redirected to http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk

what client are you using that doesn't redirect?

Comment: Redirection handling was added with 1.7.0, so if he's using a client older than that he'd get that error.

Comment: i am using the default that came with IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

On your SVN client give the URL as http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/
ViewVC may or may not give you extact details while performing a checkout.